# What will happen to wing Vortices on supersonic aircraft?

Tags: supersonic

Having looked at the new Aerion AS2 design I wondered whether anyone could tell me what happens to wingtip vortices at a cruise of Mach 1.4 with the strange wing shape of the AS2 design? I know that induced drag (very closely associated with wingtip vortices) reduces with velocity, and that many supersonic aircraft work by vortex lift using delta wing configurations, but the AS2 has bizarrely conventional stubby wings. can anyone help?

Comment: Induced drag is not associated with wingtip vortices.  Induced drag is associated with the lift-generation process deflecting air downwards when it was previously going straight backwards, thus decreasing the backwards-going part of the air's motion and pushing backwards on the aircraft.